# allow numbers, dots and backspace and delete in textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox

i have the following code:

```
Private Sub TxtPStof_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtPStof.KeyPress
    e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = ".")

End Sub
```

which allows only digits and . in my textbox, however i also need to be able to delete values using the backspace or the delete button.

Is this possible?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I totally agree with the answer from Konrad Rudolph
(It's really a messy affair to handle the user input in the KeyPress event)
I wish to give an answer at your question.

The MSDN in the [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Y399) docs states that `The KeyPress event is not raised by noncharacter keys`. This means that you don't get the Delete key, but only the BackSpace key. You could handle this situation with this little change to your event handler

```
Private Sub TxtPStof_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtPStof.KeyPress 

    if e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back then
        e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = ".") 
    end if

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you steve, i know its a bit messy, but it was the fastest way to do it for me, and the program wont be used by multiple ppl, just 1 person really, so it's not an issue for me, even tough it's messy. i'll be looking into the validating event later on when i have more time. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 8):

This is the wrong approach.

It’s universally agreed that restricting the user’s input is bad for the user experience, and you will invariably fail to handle special cases (what about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, for instance? Ah, you forgot about that. Everybody does).

Instead, .NET offers the [`Validating` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) for validating user input. You should intercept *that* event, *not* the keypress. *Do* allow users to enter text however they want; in particular, allow them to make mistakes (e.g. mistyping) without interruption – that would be extremely disruptive and *not* helpful.

Then, once they’re finished (because input focus leaves the control), do an input validation in one go.

Answer (score 0):

```
If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = ControlChars.Back Or e.KeyChar = "." Then

        e.Handled = False

Else

        e.Handled = True

End If
```

Comment: This is code smell: `If x Then variable = False Else variable = True` should be rewritten as `variable = Not x`.

Answer (score 0):

this code works fine for me.

```
 If Not ((Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 48 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 57) Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 46 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 127) Then
        e.KeyChar = ""
        e.Handled = False
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
        If Not (Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 46) Then e.Handled = True
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub textbox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles textbox.KeyPress
    If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
        e.Handled = True

    End If
End Sub
```

This should do what you want it to do.

Comment: Can you please add some explanation, why should use this code?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        Dim NumString = "0123456789.-"
        If Not NumString.Contains(e.KeyChar) Then
            If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then  'BackSpace is allowed
                e.KeyChar = ""
            End If
        Else
            If e.KeyChar = "-" Then
                If Len(Trim(TxtDcrAmt.Text)) > 0 Then
                    e.KeyChar = ""
                End If
            End If

            If e.KeyChar = "." Then
                If TxtDcrAmt.Text.Contains(".") Then
                    e.KeyChar = ""
                End If
            End If

            If TxtDcrAmt.Text.Contains(".") Then
                Dim TLen As Integer = 0
                TLen = TxtDcrAmt.Text.IndexOf(".") + 2
                If Len(Trim(TxtDcrAmt.Text)) > TLen Then
                    e.KeyChar = ""
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score -1):

Put this on keypress event. This allows dots and numbers only

```
If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
            If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 46 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Or (Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 And Asc(e.KeyChar) > 46) Then
                e.Handled = True
      End If
End If
```